# Explode dataframe column into rows on numbering instead of comma

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I want my dataframe from this.....

| Name | Qualities |
| --- | --- |
| boba fet | 1. Fighting 2. Running 3.swimming |
| enigma | 1. Dodging bullets while running, cooking food 2. Sleep walking |

To the below format..

| Name | Qualities |
| --- | --- |
| boba fet | Fighting |
| boba fet | Running |
| boba fet | Swimming |
| enigma | Dodging bullets while running, cooking food |
| enigma | Sleep walking |

Even if there is comma in text it needs to be exploded into rows on the numberings.

I tried to do

`df.assign(Qualities = df.Qualities.str.split('1.')).explode('Qualities')` but didn't get the desired result.

Comment: Please add `dataframe` or/and `pandas` tags, so people will distinguish questions much better

Comment: Try split on regex [`r'\d+\.'`](https://akuiper.com/console/MZF2lICGc-RP)

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html#pandas.Series.str.split

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could split on the number and period as the delimiter using regex.  You'll end up with a few empty rows and whitespace using this pattern, so you can strip the values and drop empty rows.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['boba fet', 'enigma'],
 'Qualities': ['1. Fighting 2. Running 3.swimming',
  '1. Dodging bullets while running, cooking food 2. Sleep walking']})

df['Qualities'] = df.Qualities.str.split('\d+.\s?')
df = df.explode('Qualities')
df['Qualities'] = df['Qualities'].str.strip()
print(df.loc[df['Qualities'].ne('')])
```

Comment: I replaced 1. with empty string and 2. 3. 4. with ';' and then did ```df.assign(Qualities = df.Qualities.str.split(';')).explode('Qualities')``` and it also worked fine. But this one also works.